# Blazor: Reusable OnSelect Change Event

Tags: c#, onchange, blazor-server-side, selectionchanged

Is there a more reusable version of this:

```
 void OnSelectFoundWithCus(ChangeEventArgs e)
 {
     selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
     DisplayToggle("FoundWithCus");
 }
 async Task DisplayToggle(string DivToToggle)
 {
    if(selectedString == "Yes")
    //if (!isChecked)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("showElement", new { id = DivToToggle });
        isChecked = !isChecked;
    }
    else
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("hideElement", new { id = DivToToggle });
        isChecked = !isChecked;
    }
 }
```

I'd like to have one reusable method that I can pass through a string for what Div to hide/show, but it doesn't seem to be an option with a ChangeEventArgs method.  There's several controls that the users want toggled between hidden and visible based off option selections (all yes/no).  Ideally, I'd rather just have one method that I could use like this:

```
 void OnSelect(ChangeEventArgs e, string DivToToggle)
 {
     selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
     DisplayToggle(DivToToggle);
 }
```

Trying to use the method of changing the classes like this:

```
<div class="@className"></div>
```

Then

```
void OnSelect(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
    if (selectedString == "No")
    {
        className = "form-group row";
    }
    else
    {
        className = "Invisible";
    }        
}
```

Results in every control using class="@className" being displayed/hidden when any of the controls referencing it select an option.

Comment: Where would that `string DivToToggle` be coming from? Irrespective to that, you should probably rewrite this completely to not invoke any javascript. Just include some sort of `class="@display_or_not"` in your divs and make sure you change the respective `display_or_not` variables in the respective click handlers.

Comment: Initial thought is on the actual <select> control itself.  Something like: @onchange='(() => OnSelect("FoundWithCus"))'.  Is there an example of that class="@display_or_not" I can reference?

Comment: It's just [basic syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#conditional-html-element-attributes).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I may have asked the wrong question.  Basically, I needed to pass additional parameters to a function with a ChangeEventArgs parameter.  So far, the first functional version of this I found is this setup (until I can get a non-JavaScript version working):

For the select control:

```
 <select @onchange='(e  => DisplayToggle(e, "DMGReported"))' class="form-control">
     <option value=" "> </option>
     <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
 </select>
```

For the C#:

```
async Task DisplayToggle(ChangeEventArgs e, string DivToToggle)
{
    selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
    if (selectedString == "Yes")        
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("showElement", new { id = DivToToggle });
        selectedString = "";
    }
    else
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("hideElement", new { id = DivToToggle });
        selectedString = "";
    }
}
```

And for the IJSRuntime:

```
function hideElement(styleOp) {
    document.getElementById(styleOp.id).style.display = "none";
}
function showElement(styleOp) {
    document.getElementById(styleOp.id).style = null;
    document.getElementById(styleOp.id).style.visibility = "visible";    
}
```